# What is SNOT building?

Tags: terminology, snot

I have seen reference on LEGO forums to "SNOT building". This sounds gross! Are there really squishy-sticky LEGO bricks, or what?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

SNOT stands for **S**tuds **N**ot **O**n **T**op and it means building structures where you use hinges or other techniques to change the direction of the bricks, so they are not one on top of the other as it's done traditionally.

This is a very simple example of SNOT:

[image: Example of LEGO SNOT]

The technique is particularly useful for spaceships and even some LEGO sets rely on it, for example, look at the wings of the [Imperial Shuttle (10212)](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Imperial-Shuttle-10212):

[image: LEGO Imperial Shuttle 10212]

as well as any of the star destroyers, like the latest one, the [Super Star Destroyer (10221)](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Super-Star-Destroyer-10221) (the surfaces near the borders are placed at an angle):

[image: Super Star Destroyer 10221]

There are many ways of performing this technique. Swooshable's [SNOT reference tool](http://swooshable.com/snot/) has many more practical examples.

Comment: There are two variants of the Imperial Shuttle. Both rely on the SNOT design. {I have the newer version of the Imperial Shuttle.}