# What different bricks exist with studs on the sides?

Tags: building, snot

(Partially inspired by [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/61/82).)

I have been wondering recently just how many different LEGO bricks there are with studs on the side.

Which LEGO **bricks** have studs specifically on the sides?

*Note:* I am asking about bricks, not plates and/or other types of elements.

Comment: ... how is this question "not constructive"?

Comment: First, it's really two questions. The first question is difficult to answer because it would be an enormous and constantly-growing list. Also, the second part is problematic, because there's no real answer - there are an infinite number of ways to SNOT build, and we have no idea whether or not a brick was "designed" for SNOT building. So I too have to vote to close.

Comment: Should I delete this question, then?

Comment: Well, that's up to you and everyone else. It's received two close votes, but also two upvotes, and the site is what all the users make of it. I think questions along the lines of "I want this effect, how do I build it?" are going to be much more useful than "What effects exist of type X?" The former represent real problems people may Google for. The latter is only of interest to people who generally already know everything about Lego, and can never be completely answered because people keep inventing new things to do.

Comment: I really want to answer this question, but I can't figure out where to start. The second part is almost impossible to answer (have you seen plates back-to-back, hold together with levers?), not mentionning that even LEGO used non-SNOT-specific parts to achieve a SNOT effect. And the first part... well, I guess a lot of parts can fit the bill, but maybe some others aren't as clear a case.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: I've edited the question to make it specific to bricks.

Comment: I go with Joe Wreschnig on this one. The list is too long because it covers any piece that is used in a SNOT way (which could be all pieces)

Comment: @pcantin I specifically wrote: "bricks, not plates and/or other types of elements".

Comment: @PeterDC I think the complexity of the question is in the semantic.  What is a brick? To me a plate is a specialization of a brick, so when I read 'bricks' in your question I think of a lot of pieces.  To me this was confusing.

Comment: I'm still not sure about this question. Even if I restrict myself to bricks, I feel like it'll be long list, and one no one will learn anything from. No one approaches a problem like "How can I build SNOT?" or "What bricks have studs on the side?"- rather things like "How can I get an angle four studs wide and eight studs tall with a flat-ish surface?" or "Has Lego made a brick that will provide stability between these two specific parts?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of elements shown (together with other possibilities and SNOT-techniques) at [holgermatthes.de](http://www.holgermatthes.de/bricks/en/snot.php), where there are pieces that are really **bricks with side-studs** (excluding all the other possibilities for SNOT-building) are those (+ [the headlight/erling-brick](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-is-an-erling-brick) and [the big gray blocks you can see here](http://www.holgermatthes.de/bricks/data/images/technics/snot-example-3.jpg), which are not shown in the following image):

[image: Bricks with Knobs]

Comment: LEGO lists these as "With Knobs" on their Pick-a-Brick tools, i.e. "1x4 With 4 Knobs" (Design ID 30414), or "1x1 With 2 Knobs" (Design ID 87087). They call the Erling-Brick an "Angular Brick 1x1" (Design ID 4070). http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Pick-A-Brick-11998