# I want to recreate a few things I saw but I don't know what pieces I need. Can you identify these bricks?

Tags: part-identification

I want to recreate a few things I saw but I don't know what pieces I need. Can you identify these bricks so I can buy them on Bricklink?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of the bricks seen there are fairly common - plates, tiles, round bricks (2x2, 1x1 and cone 1x1).

Among the "uncommon" parts I can tell:

- [Technic thick liftarm, 2-long](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43857&C=7) in blue.
- [Round 1x1 plate with swirl](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15470&C=95), in silver.
- [1x2 plate with perpendicular technic pin on top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11458&C=1), in white.
- I can't tell exactly how the 6-stud-long round parts of the scroll are done, but I suspect some clever SNOT plus something like [1x2x1 curved slope](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=37352&C=1) in white.
- [Barb/Claw/Horn/Tooth (small)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=53451) in either silver or pearl grey.
- [Bar 4L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30374&C=88) in reddish brown.

The SNOT in the scroll is particularly tricky - the correct alignment between a curved slope and the 2x2 round bricks cannot be achieved with the usual parts used for SNOT, as far as I can tell (bricks with stud on side, etc).

For that SNOT assembly, I'll suggest using [1x1 plate with bar handle on long stem](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=79194)  together with [1x1 plate with horizontal clip](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4085d) plus a few plates, like so:

[image: SNOT assembly]

As for the stickers, they seem custom-made.

Comment: What's SNOT? I've not heard that one before.

Comment: See https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/61/what-is-snot-building

Comment: I got some Technic thick liftarm, 2-long in blue and Round 1x1 plate with swirl, in silver and some Bar 4L in reddish brown. I tried putting it all together and the bars are too small to hold it all together...they  fall out of the Round plates and liftarms.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot know how it is held internally. Maybe they're held by non-lego means, such as plasticine or clay.

Comment: Bars inserted through technic pins?