# Technique for connecting a tile vertically next to a brick

Tags: building, connections

I'm trying to create this effect, where a 1x1 half-circle tile seems to 'stick out of' a 2x2 brick at 90 degrees:

[image: desired look: 2x2 brick with half-circle tile "sticking out"]

This is easily achieved with a 1x1 tile with light attachment, as seen here from the back:

[image: same thing, from the back, with tile-with-light-attachment]

However, that particular piece is quite expensive in my chosen color (either orange or dark orange).

I've tried using a technic axle-and-pin connector, but it looks very bulky and the pin itself is also not available in (dark) orange:

[image: bulky alternative using technic pieces]

I've also tried various brackets in different configurations, but since they're all square, the edges stick out from under the half-circle tile.

Are there other ways to achieve the same, or a similar looking effect?

Answer (score 12):

Some ideas given the color constraints (all used parts are available in Orange, except those not visible). Perhaps none are very compelling, but they might point you in a different direction.

If you're not afraid of stressing bricks a bit (only during (dis)assembly - when assembled, there's no stress), using [Hinge Plate 1 x 2 Locking with 2 Fingers on Side and 7 Teeth (50340)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50340#T=C&C=4) :

[image]

**This next one doesn't actually work as pointed out in comments - the rod attached to the hand is too thin to stay put. Leaving it here in case someone knows of a trick to make it work anyway.** When it's acceptable that the tile is slightly off angle, using [Hand (983)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=983#T=C&C=4)
and [Technic, Brick 1 x 1 with Axle Hole (73230)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=73230#T=C&C=4) :

[image]

Using [Slope, Curved 1 x 1 x 2/3 Double (49307)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=49307#T=C&C=4) instead of the tile :

[image]

And finally, a very rough approximation of the shape using [Hinge Plate 1 x 2 Locking with 1 Finger on Side (44567)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44567#T=C&C=4) (assuming your requirements are quite flexible) :

[image]

Comment: Those are all great ideas! I love the hand piece with the brick with axle hole. I tried it out with an actual hand I took out of a minifig, but it didn't really stay in place in the axle hole for me. Am I missing something there?

Comment: @jqno : you're right - it doesn't work. I thought it was closer to the thickness of a bar, but it's not. Should have tried it out physically before posting. I'll mark it as unusable in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps too straightforward: placing tiles between studs is a legal technique (so are plates by the way if the studs where you insert the plate between are hollow):

[image]

Comment: Oooh that's inventive! But it will leave a vertical slit down the front of I place two of them next to each other. I was hoping to keep that a single piece. I don't suppose there's a 2x2 brick with studs on the sides?

Comment: Not a brick, but there's a  modified 2x2 plate with studs on the side in orange. https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99206#T=S&C=4&O={%22color%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22BE%22,%22iconly%22:0}

Answer (score 7):

I'll suggest using a 1x1 plate with clip, recessed half a stud by means of a jumper plate:

[image: CAD diagram]

I haven't tested this physically, but I assume that the clip will be under stress since (in this assembly) the round tile won't fit through the entire clip.

---

If you're OK with using *dark* orange, then you can use [1x2 plate round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=35480) with some SNOT to achieve the effect:

[image: CAD diagram]

Comment: Dark orange is fine. The round 1x2 plates are a good idea, but can you describe how they connect to the other bricks? I'm afraid I can't really tell from the image.

Comment: I've pictured generic [SNOT](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/61/what-is-snot-building) - there are dozens of ways to achieve it. See e.g. [the unofficial LEGO advanced building techniques guide](https://joncraton.org/media/files/UnofficialLEGOAdvancedBuildingTechniquesGuide.pdf) for specific SNOT techniques.